# ‘bin needs to download the font “Nanum Myeongjo”’

Tags: virus

My Mac gave me a pop up that asked "bin needs to download the font “Nanum Myeongjo” I clicked it away and ran Malwarebytes which found and quarantined "Adware.Spigot". Am I fine? Should I still be worried? I am using 10.12.6 on a 2015 Macbook Pro 15 inch.

Answer (score 1):

Nanum Myeongjo is a [free Google font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nanum+Myeongjo). When a program asks to download a font, it is because it is because it calls for it but it is missing from your font library. This is a normal behavior, but you can ignore it if you want.

The Adware.Spigot is most likely **unrelated to the font** and is not a virus, but it is [Adware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adware). Adware is not a virus, but it can be considered [Malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware), which is an unwanted program. I would recommend removing it.